# Javascript - Some methods of an object are defined and others are not outside the object

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I'm having a strange issue in which accessing some methods of an object returns an "x is not a function" error, but accessing other methods returns no issue. typeof queries confirm that it's not defined, but the strange thing is that it only seems undefined outside of the object - calls within the object resolve without a hitch. I'll post the code below.

tile.js

```
class Tile{
  constructor(x, y, z, b){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.board = b;
    console.log(typeof(this.getBoard()));//returns "function"
    this.bot = "NONE";
  }

  setBot(b){
    this.bot = b;
  }

  getBoard(){
    return this.board;
  }

}

module.exports = Tile;
```

bot.js

```
class Bot {

  constructor(t, p) {

    this.tile = t;

    console.log(typeof(this.tile.setBot));//returns "function"
    console.log(typeof(this.tile.getBoard));//returns "undefined"
    this.tile.setBot(this);
    this.tile.getBoard().getBots().addBot(this);//throws not a function error

  }

  getTile(){
    return this.tile;
  }


}
module.exports = Bot;
```

EDIT: These methods are being called from here.

```
var Board = require('./tiles/board.js');
var Tires = require('./parts/core/tires.js');
var Bot = require('./bot.js');

class GameInstance{
  constructor(){
    this.board = new Board();
    this.players = new Map();
    var t = new Tires();
    var b = new Bot(t, this.board.getTile(3,3));
  }
}

module.exports = GameInstance;
```

Comment: how are you calling it all?

Comment: Edited that in.

Comment: _"console.log(typeof(this.tile.getBoard));//returns "undefined""_ Cannot reproduce. What is `b`? Where is `getBots` and `addBot` defined?

Comment: They're defined in a class called Board, but they aren't relevant as the disappearance of getBoard happens first.

Comment: @junkmail _"but they aren't relevant as the disappearance of getBoard happens first"_ What do you mean by "disappearance"? `console.log(typeof(this.tile.getBoard))` logs `function` at `console` here given code at Question. See https://stackoeverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is `tires.js`? Avoid creating single letter variable names. You're passing in a `Tire` object into your `Bot` constructor. I'm pretty sure you're meaning to pass in a `Tile` object.